# Lack of opportunity for a mitzvah being a good thing

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Rabbi Yochanan said fortunate is he who has no parents (Kiddushin 31b) - because it is almost impossible for someone with parents to honor them appropriately.
I have heard that Esther succeeded at overcoming Haman because Eisav's zchus was kibud av. No one with parents honored them more than Eisav. But since Esther did not have parents, her desire to be able to fulfill kibud av v'eim was considered as if she fulfilled the mitzvah completely.

Is there any other mitzvah like this where someone without the opportunity to fulfill it is considered greater in that area than someone with the opportunity? Specifically, what about people who can't have children?